# Is there a way to search an OU and add missing members to a security group?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get away from using the Quest tool AD snap-in and need help re-writing a PowerShell script that updates AD group members based on if they are in an OU or not. Can someone help?

Examples of how it is coded currently to the snap-in.

```
$null=Get-QADUser -NotMemberOf "Domain\Group-A" -SearchRoot "OU=Users,DC=Test" | Add-QADGroupMember "Domain\Group-A"

$null=Get-QADComputer -NotMemberOf "Domain\Group-B" -SearchRoot "OU=Computers,DC=Test" | Add-QADGroupMember "Domain\Group-B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on availability (and permissions) there's the RSAT ActiveDirectory powershell module providing cmdlets like `Get-AdUser -LdapFilter ... -SearchBase ...` that you can use to achieve this.

Syntax is more verbose - for example, it doesn't care for RDN -- but is still rather brief.

Without the ActiveDirectory module you need to set up and implement your own LDAP queries using `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory`.
This will be (very) verbose but it will work on any windows machine that's in active support.

Major difference to what you have right now is that you can't just `-NotMemberOf <AdGroupPrincipal>`. Instead, you'll have to use LdapFilter, memberof attribute and a distinguished name (FQDN rather than RDN) to identify the group you want the member of. Then negate the result for something like

```
(!(memberof=cn=GroupName,OU=groupOU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=lan))
```

If you prefer to stick to one/two liners then you'll probably want to keep using Quest. Especially if using RSAT ActiveDirectory module is not a viable option you're likely to get hundreds of lines rather than the two.